# Is it possible to display a new page when using asp.net modalpopupextender?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender, shadowbox

From the examples I've seen the [modal popup extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) can open panels which exist on the same page. 
Would that be possible to open a new page with this control?

A behaviour similar to http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

I'm looking to use the modal pop-up extender as it's free whereas the shadowbox js is not.

Answer (score 0):

Popup the in-page div/panel containing `IFrame` - you can set iframe's source to other page.